# English text inside a Hebrew paragraph

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I am using XeLaTeX + polyglossia for Hebrew typesetting, and this works wonderfully. However, recently I needed to incorporate English words inside Hebrew paragraphs. This compiles wrong, as it attaches every non-letter character (such as commas, parenthesis, etc...) to the English LTR, well it should stay RTL.

It's easier to give an example than to explain it literally, so here's an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
אלף (Aleph), גימל (Gimmel).
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: aleph gimmel]

where it should produce

[image: aleph gimmel]

Anything I am doing wrong?

## Update

I have tried using the `english` environment around the English text, but that has produced extra spaces, and anyway very cumbersome...

The code:

```
\begin{document}
אלף
\begin{english}(Aleph)\end{english},
גימל
\begin{english}(Gimmel)\end{english}.
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of the answer and comments in [Latin characters with accents inside a Hebrew paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283747/latin-characters-with-accents-inside-a-hebrew-paragraph), I have figured out that the solution to this issue is simply using the command `\textenglish`. This is the full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}

\begin{document}
אלף (\textenglish{Aleph}), גימל (\textenglish{Gimmel}).
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: Aleph Gimmel - ok]