# Using -- to produce Kav Mafrid (Hebrew dash) in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, punctuation, polyglossia, hebrew

I am using XeLaTeX + polyglossia for Hebrew typesetting. Recently I have encountered an issue with producing dashes (**Kav Mafrid**, in Hebrew) in Hebrew texts. The issue arises when I am using `newfontfamily` instead of `setmainfont`.

To be more precise, here is an example. When I am using `setmainfont`, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{David CLM}
\setsansfont{Simple CLM}
\setmonofont{Miriam Mono CLM}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
קו -- מפריד.
\end{document}
```

produces the right output:

[image: kav mafrid - ok]

However, the compilation in that case is very slow (I have no idea why, but it runs `xelatex` 6 times), and I have issues including Latin characters with accents inside Hebrew paragraphs (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283747/latin-characters-with-accents-inside-a-hebrew-paragraph?lq=1)).

The better practice is, perhaps, to use `newfontfamily`. In that case, this is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
קו -- מפריד.
\end{document}
```

In that case, the compilation is very quick (only a single call to `xelatex`), and some issues with Latin characters are solved, but the output is the following:

[image: kav mafrid - wrong]

Any idea what I can do to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `Ligatures=TeX` to your fontfamily options.

Comment: `Ligatures=TeX` is enabled by default with recent versions of `fontspec`.

Comment: I have added `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` just after loading `fontspec`, and it did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg I'm using the most recent version, and it doesn't do that with Bach's MWE.