# Specify Hebrew font but keep Computer Modern for english

Tags: fontspec, hebrew

I want to use a font I downloaded from the internet in my LaTeX document.

Let's call this font AWESOME.

I noticed in the [`fontspec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) manual, §2.2, Font selection/ By file name, the following specification:

```
\setmainfont{AWESOME}[
Language=Hebrew, % Do I really need this key?
Script=Hebrew,
Extension = .ttf,
Path = /Users/the_user_name/path-to-files/ ,
UprightFont = *-Medium ,
BoldFont = *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-MediumOblique,
ItalicFont = *-MediumOblique]
```

So, Hebrew text is now used with the new font AWESOME, but English text is typeset with that same AWESOME font (which apparently has English script in it).

How do I tell XeLaTeX to keep use (the default) Computer Modern for every other Latin letters in my document?

Moreover, I want in the future to download a new font to be used for English (let's call this English font MARVELOUS). What is the command to be used to set it up only for English? Some thing like

```
\SetMainEnglishFontOnly{MARVELOUS}[
Script=English,
Extension = .ttf,
Path = /Users/the_user_name/path-to-files/,
UprightFont = *-Medium,
etc...
]
```

I am using `polyglossia` as the package that facilitates the multilingual typesetting:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
```

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283777/47927 .

Comment: My font is not in the texmf tree. Therefore I am looking for a command that specifies its path.

Comment: You can use the same options for `\newfontfamily` as there are for `\setmainfont`, that is, you can also set the `Path` for the font with `\newfontfamily`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to define a font family called `\hebrewfont`. You might also need to define `\hebrewfontsf` or `\hebrewfonttt` if you plan to use sans serif and monospaced fonts for Hebrew.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{FreeSerif}[
  Extension=.otf,
  Path=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gnu-freefont/,
  UprightFont=*,
  ItalicFont=*Italic,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldItalic,
]

\begin{document}

לוח את והוא מדעי בגרסה, לעריכת הנאמנים ופיתוחה שתי גם, בה בלשנות פסיכולוגיה אתה. מתוך לטיפול למאמרים ב שער. לעריכת אינטרנט לוח או, זכר דת לציין הבאים. כתב שנתי בשפה לחשבון על. כלשהו והנדסה על כדי, ויקי רביעי טכניים אם אנא. בדפים קודמות הקהילה ארץ אל.

דת שתפו המדינה טכנולוגיה אחר, אם לערך מיזמי בקר, מלא הבקשה הקנאים או. מתוך מיזמים צ'ט דת. מיזמי ולחבר בחירות את בדף, מה צעד ראשי הנדסת. טכניים אגרונומיה כלל את, אל שתי לטיפול סוציולוגיה.

בקרבת סטטיסטיקה ויש אם. תנך הראשי אנציקלופדיה על, מתן אם שתפו ספינות הגולשות. ב אחר יסוד הנדסת ייִדיש, כלל אל המזנון גיאוגרפיה. ב קצרמרים היסטוריה סוציולוגיה שער, שנתי לערכים אקטואליה שמו את. מה שתי יידיש המשפט, היא שנורו בגרסה ב. מדע את כלשהו אקראי תיקונים.


\begin{english}
The Hebrew text above has been automatically generated and should mean
nothing at all.

Source: \texttt{https://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/\_hebrew}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

In the example I defined the font family with an explicit path (even if it points to a font already available in TeX Live).

[image]

Here's what `pdffonts` tells about the generated PDF:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TKCDTV+FreeSerif-Identity-H          CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
QIVRSP+LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
UJPWFA+LMMono10-Regular-Identity-H   CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In much the same, I can also do `\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Arial}` or `\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{DownloadedFont}[Extension = .ttf,Path = /Users/the_user_name/path-to-files/, etc..]`, right?

Comment: @tush I guess so. And a short experiment shows it works.

Comment: Just tried your advise, but the font used for some cited works, through `biblatex`s `\cite{}`, is not printed with the Latin Modern Roman font. An image of the output can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627258/). Do you know how to fix this?